# Criterion for minimality of resolution of singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have several questions about minimal resolution of singularity of a surface.

First, there is a criterion I found and I couldn't understand : "Let $V$ a surface with an isolated singularity. A resolution $\pi : W \to V$ is minimal if and only if the exceptional fiber $\pi^{-1}(o)$ does not contains exceptional curves of the first kind." (Such curves are curves isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ and have self intersection number $-1$). I have no ideas why this criterion is true : one direction is easy by the Castelnovo's criterion but I have no idea for the converse.

More general questions : even if they seems really natural, why are minimal resolutions useful ? How to compute them (again I'm happy with just the case of surfaces !)

Comment: If I understand your question, I think you are asking about the existence of a resolution. This is not easy and better to read the proof somewhere. It can be found in many places (positive characteristic case is a bit harder).

Comment: I'm asking a stupider question : assuming there is at least one resolution, is it obvious that when we blow down every exceptionnal curve of first kind we get a minimal resolution ?

Comment: @Mohan : If you have any indications for this I would really appreciate ! I don't know a lot about algebraic surfaces so this is a bit new for me, sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: That is the definition of a minimal resolution. Do you have a different definition?

Comment: My definition is : for all resolution $W' \to V$ there is a unique morphism $W' \to W$ in which the resolution factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that there *is* a minimal resolution $W$.  If $W'$ is a resolution that is not minimal, then there exists $W' \to W$, which is a proper birational morphism between surfaces.  General theory tells us that it is given by blowing down some $-1$ curves, and so $W'$ must contain $-1$ curves.

More generally, if $W$ contains no $-1$ curves, then for the same reason there cannot exist a non-trivial proper birational map $W \to W'$ with $W'$ also being non-singular,
and is the general reason that a non-minimal resolution must contain $-1$ curves.

Comment: Dear tracing thanks a lot for your answer ! I need to learn a bit about surface I guess.